# Jogl display not showing up

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to find an openGL library that works using NetBeans on IBM or Mac for a 3D graphics course I teach.  JOGL seemed a good choice.  I tried loading the JGears demo.  Though the code appears to run (all the Graphics2D components display), the gears are invisible.  As far as I can tell, the Animator isn't even calling the display method.

Comment: What platform are you running on? What have you tried? Have you looked at an error log? Tried getting the output of glError()? You are not really giving any details other than you tried running the code and it didn't work.